# How to efficiently use Django bulk_update

Tags: python, django

```
def upload_file(request):
if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
    file = request.FILES.get('file')
    righe = creatore_lista_numeri(file)
    data_fubatura = dt.now()  # - timedelta(weeks=3)
    numeri_esistenti = set(
        NumeroDiTelefono.objects.values_list('numero', flat=True))
    numeri_esistenti_da_confrontare = set(NumeroDiTelefono.objects.filter(
        Q(data_ultima_fubatura__lte=data_fubatura - timedelta(days=15)) | Q(data_ultima_fubatura=None)).values_list('numero', flat=True))

    numeri_da_creare = []
    numeri_gia_presenti = []
    numeri_gia_presenti_da_confrontare = []
    for riga in righe:
        numero_telefono = pulisci_numero_telefono(str(riga).strip())
        if not numero_telefono:
            continue
        if numero_telefono not in numeri_esistenti:
            numeri_da_creare.append(NumeroDiTelefono(
                numero=numero_telefono, data_prima_fubatura=data_fubatura, data_ultima_fubatura=data_fubatura, fine_fubatura=data_fubatura))
            numeri_esistenti.add(numero_telefono)
        else:
            numeri_gia_presenti.append(numero_telefono)
        if numero_telefono in numeri_esistenti_da_confrontare:
            # numero_da_modificare, created = NumeroDiTelefono.objects.update_or_create(
            #     numero=numero_telefono,
            #     defaults={
            #         'data_ultima_fubatura': data_fubatura,
            #         'fine_fubatura': data_fubatura
            #     }
            # )
            numero_da_modificare = NumeroDiTelefono.objects.get(
                numero=numero_telefono)
            numero_da_modificare.data_ultima_fubatura = data_fubatura
            numero_da_modificare.fine_fubatura = data_fubatura
            numero_da_modificare.save()
            numeri_gia_presenti_da_confrontare.append(numero_da_modificare)
    numeri_creati = NumeroDiTelefono.objects.bulk_create(numeri_da_creare)
    lista_numeri_presenti = [numero.numero for numero in numeri_creati]
    numeri_da_creare = serializers.serialize('json', numeri_da_creare)
    numeri_gia_presenti_da_confrontare = serializers.serialize(
        'json', numeri_gia_presenti_da_confrontare)
    data = {
        'nome_file': file.name,
        'numeri_da_creare': numeri_da_creare,
        'lista_numeri_presenti': lista_numeri_presenti,
        'numeri_gia_presenti': numeri_gia_presenti,
        'numeri_gia_presenti_da_confrontare': numeri_gia_presenti_da_confrontare,
    }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

As you may see, I am basically creating or updating a list of phone numbers. My problem here is that the function works but, especially for the updating part, is totally inefficient. I have to create or update thousands of records. While creating is very fast, updating is extremely slow. I tried with the update_or_create, update or the classic get and save methods but none is efficient.
I am trying to understand how to properly use `bulk_update` method but so far I didn't find a way to use it.

Comment: What you can try - put the for .. save loop into a transaction, this should speedup `.save` loops alot. For `bulk_update` - you'd have to collect create update cases separately first, then call either `bulk_create` or `bulk_update`.